# JSONRepresentation of NSObject Data Model

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I am trying to parse all the data that I have populated in my data model. I have some nsmutabledictionary within the nsobject, and just curious is it possible to get jsonrepresentation of that object type? I got Not valid type for JSON using ASIHTTPREQUEST. So the obvious concern here is, if that is possible or I have to iterate through the object's and insert it in nsdictionary and then parse it?

Thanks

Comment: You could iterate thru the iVars using reflection, if thats what you want, however, it would be pretty much impossible to get the types of the iVars, as objc isn't a strongly typed language.

Comment: are you using any kind of `JSON` library (like [SBJSON](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/)) or iOS 5.0's `NSJSONSerialization` class?

Comment: I am using SBJSON, haven't switched to iOS 5 yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to checkout my implementation for serializing NSObjects to JSON and vice versa - https://github.com/QBurst/KVCObjectSerializer

Comment: Mahadevan, pretty kool stuff you have written. I am using one method as a standard way of utilizing the serialization is by creating a class and inserting all my known types objects in it, and then iterating through nsdictionary so it can get serialized for json. I notice in your code you are doing that in your KVCObjectBase which is great. Keep up the good stuff.

Comment: hi Mahadevan Sreenivasan i check your profile but i cant find your email address, to ask you about the OBJC_JSONSerializer class

Comment: The above link works now. You can pull the latest code from there!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer your question completely without knowing more about the objects you're trying to serialize to JSON, but it's not hard to explain what objects can be serialized (assuming you're using TouchJSON). If you take a look at the `-isValidJSONObject` method in [CJSONSerializer.m](https://github.com/TouchCode/TouchJSON/blob/master/Source/JSON/CJSONSerializer.m), you'll see exactly what classes can be serialized:

```
- (BOOL)isValidJSONObject:(id)inObject
    {
    if ([inObject isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) { return(YES); }
    else if ([inObject isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) { return(YES); }
    else if ([inObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) { return(YES); }
    else if ([inObject isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) { return(YES); }
    else if ([inObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) { return(YES); }
    else if ([inObject isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) { return(YES); }
    else if ([inObject respondsToSelector:@selector(JSONDataRepresentation)])
    {
        return(YES);
    }
    else
    {
        return(NO);
    }
}
```

(Code reformatted for clarity.)

So, you can see that NSNULL, NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, NSDictionary, and NSData are all serializable to JSON, and that any class that implements `-JSONDataRepresentation` is also serializable.

Based on the "Not valid type for JSON" error that you're apparently getting, I'd guess that at least one of the objects in you graph is not among those listed above, and you'll probably want to implement `-JSONDataRepresentation` in the corresponding class(es).

**Update:** From your comment, I see that you're using SBJSON instead of TouchJSON. [This page](http://stig.github.com/json-framework/api/3.0/objc2json.html) has the list of types supported by SBJSON.

Comment: wow I didn't know TouchJSON can do that, I am using ASIHTTPRequest and i don't think such library have JSONDataRepresentation, anyways but its using SBJSON, which I guess is common with most libraries as standard and should have support but again not sure.

Comment: so its NSDictionary to object not the vice versa, which I am looking for. I guess I have to iterate through the class properties to acquire a complete set of NSDictionary. Any suggestions from your side what might be a better choice for such concern?